why infinite loop isn't working on this calculator project in hcf section?
whenever i use hcf in this calculator code infinite loop won't work but in other operations like +-*/% infinite loops works fine.how do i solve it?which should i write to allow infinte loop working even after using hcf operation.thanks in advance
heres the code
print('THIS IS A CALCULATOR PROGRAMME.')
i=1
while i==1:
    a=float(input('Enter first number:'))
    b=float(input('Enter second number:'))
    o=input('Enter operator[+,-,*,/,%,hcf]:')
    if o=='+':
        r=a+b
        print(a,o,b,'=',r)
    elif o=='-':
        r=a-b
        print(a,o,b,'=',r)
    elif o=='*':
        r=a*b
        print(a,o,b,'=',r)
    elif o=='/':
        r=a/b
        print(a,o,b,'=',r)
    elif o=='%':
        r=a%b
        print(a,o,b,'=',r)
    elif o=='hcf':
        if a<b:
            smaller=a
        else:
            smaller=b
            hcf=1
            i=1
        while i<=smaller:
            if a%i==0 and b%i==0:
                  hcf=i
                  i=i+1
                  print('THE HCF OF',a,'AND',b,'IS',hcf)
    else:
        print('OPERATOR IS INCORRECT')

i have tried to use infinite loop while using hcf operations and i expected to return to the enter a and value part but it didnt happend at all

i can get changed in the while loop for hcf, which would stop your infinite loop.

Why are you using i for both the outer and inner loops?

If i is 1 then your if statement is try correct? Then you print the hcf is 1? Do you really want to do that?

At the very least, your indentation is off. You aren't initializing hcf at all when a < b, and you aren't incrementing i when it isn't a common factor at all. That said, look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm.

The problem is that you're using i in both loops. Just swap i for something else in the HCF part, and the infinite loop will work fine.
for x in range(1, smaller + 1):
if a % x == 0 and b % x == 0:
    hcf = x

